# ORA-1008 if form variable referenced in ORDER BY Clause

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

TLDR; Is there anything I can set in an Oracle Form that would let me bind a placeholder to a `Data Block`'s `ORDER BY Clause`?

---

I'm developing a form using Oracle Form Builder 10.1.2.3.0 (because it's interfacing with a system that makes other form types undesirable).

It has a `Data Block` with `Query Data Source Type` = `Table`.

Its `WHERE Clause` allows the user to be flexible in the search, producing rows of varying interest. I want rows with a perfect match to appear before those that are not.

To implement this specification, I wrote the form's `WHERE Clause` and `ORDER BY Clause` to reflect this SQL*Plus example:

```
var sf varchar2(30)
exec :sf := 'X'

with mdual as (
   select case when level=1 then dummy else dummy || level end dummy
   from dual
   connect by level <= 2
)
select *
from  mdual
where :sf is null or dummy like '%' || upper(:sf) || '%'
order by case when :sf = dummy then 0 else 1 end asc, dummy;
```

The form variable reference is not as simple as `:sf` and the `WHERE Clause` is a bit more complicated as is the `ORDER BY Clause` but this type of query is valid. When executed in SQL*Plus, it produces exactly the type of result I desire. You can reverse the first sort expression to prove it.

When I execute the form, I get an ORA-1008 until I comment the first `ORDER BY` expression.

My conclusion is that Oracle Forms binds placeholder references in a `WHERE Clause` but not an `ORDER BY Clause`.

I could experiment with setting the `Query Data Source Type` to `Procedure` and pass the procedure the filter field but a view has more utility than a procedure and so I'd prefer to keep using the view that I've defined for the `Query Data Source Type`.

Is there a way I can coerce Oracle Forms to do what I consider the right thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **`SET_BLOCK_PROPERTY`** built-in function in order to make it dynamical and depending on a local or bind variable such as

```sql
DECLARE
  v_orderby := ' CASE WHEN '||:sf||' = ''dummy'' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, dummy';
BEGIN
  SET_BLOCK_PROPERTY('block1',ORDER_BY, v_orderby);
  EXECUTE_QUERY;
END;
```

which might be invoked from a trigger such as **`WHEN-NEW-BLOCK-INSTANCE`** after sending cursor to this block by using another action such as clicking on a button or pressing a key such as enter etc.

Comment: I placed it in the block's pre-query trigger.